# iOS Application not Writing to BLE Mini

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am designing an application which will communicate with a TI LaunchPad through a BLE Mini by utilizing CoreBluetooth, however I am struggling to transmit data between my iPhone and the Red Bear BLE Mini. Currently, I am trying to send a command which will instruct the Launchpad to turn an LED on and off. I have implemented all of the CoreBluetooth methods and confirmed that I am connected to the BLE Mini. I also have discovered this device's singular service and the five characteristics associated with this device with my iPhone application, so I know I am connected to the device. After confirming this connection, I attempted to write to the write characteristic, but I'm not sure if I wrote to this characteristic properly. Also, I'm not sure how I should be encoding the data. I have tried both ascii and utf8. Here is what I wrote:

```
let string = "LED-ON"
let data = string.data(using: .ascii)
if manager.write_char != nil{
    print("trying")
    print(manager.write_char.uuid)
    peripheral.writeValue(data!, for: manager.write_char, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse)
```

The print statement confirms that this characteristic has the uuid that I defined as being the write characteristic

```
let WRITE_CHAR = "713D0004-503E-4C75-BA94-3148F18D941E"
```

I believe this is the correct write characteristic. I have also tried 71230003. On the Launchpad side, I have uploaded the following code:

```
int incomingByte = 0;   // for incoming serial data

void setup() {
// put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(19200);
  Serial1.begin(9600);
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);     
}

void loop() {
// put your main code here, to run repeatedly: 
//if (Serial1.available()){
//    Serial.print("available");
//Read in data
   Serial.print(Serial1.available());
   Serial.print("   ");
   Serial.print(Serial1.read());
   Serial.print("\n");
   if (Serial1.available() > 0) {
     // read the incoming byte:
     incomingByte = Serial1.read();

     // say what you got:
     Serial.print("I received: ");
     Serial.println(incomingByte, DEC);
   }
}
```

In the serial monitor, all I receive are 0 from the available check and -1 from the read method both of which signify that no data is being received. Am I transmitting data to the BLE Mini correctly? If so, am I reading it incorrectly? Additionally, is there something I'm supposed to do to tell the BLE Mini to transmit data? Sorry for the long winded question. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Have you tried the "withResponse" variant? In that case, can you implement `peripheral:didWriteValueForCharacteristic:error:` in your delegate and check for any errors?

Comment: I add the didwritevalue method to the delegate, but it is not called. Any idea why this might be the case? Also I printed the properties of the characteristic and got "rawValue: 8". I'm also unsure what this means.

Comment: `peripheral:didWriteValueForCharacteristic:error:` is only called when you use `withReponse`, not when you use `withoutResponse`, as there's no way of knowing anything about the result in that situation. You may try sending data byte by byte, though I would be surprised if that was the issue. Have you tried sending data the other way around? Are you sure about the bps setting? Are you able to communicate with the BLE chip for other purposes (configuration...)?

Comment: I changed the type to be withresponse when I implemented the didWirteValue method. Also, I was able to call the read characteristic and read the prewitten value on the BLE chip, which said "Red Bear Labs", so I can definitely communicate with the chip I just dont seem to be able to write to it

Comment: If you read the Objective-C part (https://developer.apple.com/reference/corebluetooth/cbcharacteristicproperties/cbcharacteristicpropertywrite?language=objc) , you'll see that 8 for the properties, should be write (meaning you are allowed to write on this characteristic)